# GADM 4.1 Sardinia administrative boundaries does not reflect changes that occur in 2016

Tags: openstreetmap, bing-maps, gadm, italy

I am working with GADM 4.1 administrative areas and then put them into Bing Maps. I have found that those for Sardinia, Italy are not in line with changes that happened in 2016. In GADM we have:

- Cagliari
- Sassari
- Nuoro
- Oristano
- Olbia-Tempio
- Carbonia-Iglesias
- Medio Compidano
- Ogliastra

Whereas current structure confirmed by various articles, Bing Maps and Google Maps are:

- Sassari
- Oristano
- Nuoro
- Sud Sardina
- Cagliari

I found it strange, since GADM 4.1 was released in June 2022 and this change happened 7 years ago. So I have started to look at the OpenStreetMap hierarchy, and there is the same issue.

Does anyone know a structure (possible for the whole world) similar to GADM or OpenStreetMap that have updated view of the world? As I have stated before I want to put them into Bing Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia seems to disagree with itself. It lists Sardinia as having 8 NUTS-3 divisions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUTS_statistical_regions_of_Italy but only the 5 post-2016 areas here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinia#Administrative_divisions

More authoritative maps of European administrative divisions should be had from Eurostat:

https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/nuts-maps

and downloadable data for those boundaries are available from Eurostat:

https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts

in differing degrees of simplification.